# How to tell if Github code repo contains malicious code?

Tags: javascript, security, github

I am considering adding [this repository](https://github.com/skycloud1030/react-shields-badge) to my project.

Install

```
npm i react-shields-badge --save
yarn add react-shields-badge --save
```

Getting Started

```
import Badge from "react-shields-badge";
import "react-shields-badge/dist/react-shields-badge.css";

<Badge data={["npm", "v1.0.0"]} />
```

Before I do, how can I ensure there is no malicious code contained in that repo that might damage my app or do anything I don't intend it to do? (It only has like one download on NPM.)

Is there any web site for that? Or a script, program or command I can run, say, from my terminal?

Comment: There’s no reliable way to tell automatically. You can read it yourself if you want to be sure. (Read the contents of the package, though, because that’s what you install – not the code on GitHub. `npm info react-shields-badge dist.tarball`)

Comment: @Ry- Roger that. Thing is, there's this /dist file that has obfuscated code in it. I ran it through a beautifier and there was one weird line that caught my attention. But nothing definitively harmful (only because I couldn't really tell what I was reading due to the obfuscation). Any thoughts?

Comment: What was the weird line? But yes, that’s unfortunate minification. If you trust the *dependencies* (including devDependencies) of the project, you can clone/audit it from GitHub and build the same file to compare it.

Comment: @Mowzer What line?  Can you post a new question about that, specifically?

Comment: @Brad: The line is `SECRET_DO_NOT_PASS_THIS_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED` [and here is a question about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56311181/1640892)

Answer (score 2):

> how can I ensure there is no malicious code contained in that repo that might damage my app or do anything I don't intend it to do?

That's impossible.  How could software (or even a human) know what you intend to do?

> Is there any web site for that?

No, there isn't.

> Or a script, program or command I can run, say, from my terminal?

Ah, yes, the magic read-my-mind.js script...

Computers just do what we tell them.  The concept of maliciousness isn't one computers and code care about.  You could have a situation where even just a README file makes otherwise harmless code into malicious code.  For example, perhaps the README says to `rm -rf` everything, and for whatever reason you or someone else follows it.  That's not even in the code, and is quite dangerous.

The good news is that you can audit the code yourself.  You can also check in `node_modules` in your version control, if you wanted to ensure that nothing changes.  (We do have NPM and Yarn lockfiles for this, but just ensuring the exact same copy of all modules is installed is another way to solve the issue of changing un-audited depencies.)